# Handling errors in mutations

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Let's say I'm trying to create a bike as a mutation

```
var createBike = (wheelSize) => {
  if (!factoryHasEnoughMetal(wheelSize)) {
    return supplierError('Not enough metal');
  }
  return factoryBuild(wheelSize);
}
```

What happens when there's not enough steel for them shiny wheels? We'll probably need an error for the client side. How do I get that to them from my graphQL server with the below mutation:

```
// Mutations
mutation: new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'BikeMutation',
  fields: () => ({
    createBike: {
      type: bikeType,
      args: {
        wheelSize: {
          description: 'Wheel size',
          type: new graphql.GraphQLNonNull(graphql.Int)
        },
      },
      resolve: (_, args) => createBike(args.wheelSize)
    }
  })
})
```

Is it as simple as returning some error type which the server/I have defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly sure if this is what you after...

Just throw a new error, it should return something like

```
{
  "data": {
    "createBike": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Not enough metal",
      "originalError": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

your client side should just handle the response

```
if (res.errors) {res.errors[0].message}
```

What I do is passing a object with errorCode and message, at this stage, the best way to do is stringify it.

```
throw new Errors(JSON.stringify({
      code:409, 
      message:"Duplicate request......"
}))
```

NOTE: also you might be interested at this library https://github.com/kadirahq/graphql-errors

you can mask all errors (turn message to "Internal Error"), or define userError('message to the client'), which these will not get replaced.

Comment: Haha, it's so simple! Thanks for the clear response and [graphql-errors](https://github.com/kadirahq/graphql-errors)

Comment: Is the norm always to return localized messages directly from the API rather than error keys letting the client handle the translation as it pleases?